How can I use javascript modules in a web extension?
My popup.html already includes:
<script type="module" src="./popup.js"></script>
When I try to import any resource inside the script file popup.js, like:
import { Dialer } from "../common/Dialer.js";
I get the following error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

I am trying to add a click EventListener on all web pages, to listen to clicks in anchor elements of type tel, so that the extension makes the call...
Here is my manifest.json:
{
     "manifest_version": 3,
     "name": "My Extension",
     "description": "Extension"
     "version": "1.0.0",
     "permissions": [
         "storage",
         "activeTab",
         "scripting",
         "tabs"
     ],
     "action": {
         "default_popup": "./src/popup/popup.html"
     },
     "host_permissions": ["<all_urls>"],
     "content_scripts": [
         {
             "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
             "js": [
                 "./src/popup/popup.js",
                 "./src/common/DriverFactory.js",
                 "./src/chrome/ChromeDriver.js",
                 "./src/common/GenericDriver.js",
                 "./src/common/Dialer.js"
             ]
          }
     ],
     "web_accessible_resources": [{
     "resources": ["./src/images/*"],
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
     }],
     "background": {
     "service_worker": "background.js"
   }
}

I already checked the path of the imports,
Didn't export as default... so the import is correct

You load the same script as a content script and content scripts can't import modules statically, but you can do it dynamically or just don't load the script in two places.
